# How Do I Make the Images inside the div always be the size of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have set the slideshow div at 90% width so it always takes up 90% width of the screen so that it's never bigger that the width of the screen. The only problem is that the images inside don't scale to the size of the div. They either are smaller if the source image is smaller or if the image is bigger it will only show a section of the image. How do I get the images inside my slideshow to always be the width & height of the div they are in?

```css
.GalleryTXT {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 150px 0px 150px;
    }

    #cssSlider {
        width: 90%;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 4px solid #0DD587;
        margin: 40px auto;
    }

    #sliderImages {
        max-width: 4000px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* animation duration: 16s : 5x ~3s display image + 5x ~0.2s slide */
        animation: slide 16s infinite;
        -moz-animation: slide 16s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: slide 16s infinite;
        -o-animation: slide 16s infinite;
    }

    #sliderImages img {
        float: left;
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        0% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        17% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        20% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        37% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        40% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        57% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        60% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        77% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        80% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
        97% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
        100% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes slide {
        0% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        17% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        20% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        37% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        40% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        57% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        60% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        77% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        80% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
        100% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slide {
        0% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        17% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        20% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        37% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        40% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        57% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        60% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        77% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        80% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
        100% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
    }

    @-o-keyframes slide {
        0% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        17% {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        20% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        37% {
            margin-left: -800px;
        }
        40% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        57% {
            margin-left: -1600px;
        }
        60% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        77% {
            margin-left: -2400px;
        }
        80% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
        100% {
            margin-left: -3200px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="cssSlider">
    <div id="sliderImages">
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide5.jpg" alt="" />
      <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="GalleryTXT">
    <p><b>"Ordered this case just the other day & it arrived the very next day in perfect condition. The case is absolute beautiful & just makes the phone look even better which I thought wasn't even possible!, the lovely dark case helps emphasise the phones design. The case is not slippery at all & I have yet to get any marks/ damage onto it" (★★★★★)</b> - Hellen View (Google Pixel)</p><br>

    <p><b>"Ordered this case just the other day & it arrived the very next day in perfect condition. The case is absolute beautiful & just makes the phone look even better which I thought wasn't even possible!, the lovely dark case helps emphasise the phones design. The case is not slippery at all & I have yet to get any marks/ damage onto it" (★★★★★)</b> - Jordan Kean (iPhone X)</p><br>

    <p><b>"Ordered this case just the other day & it arrived the very next day in perfect condition. The case is absolute beautiful & just makes the phone look even better which I thought wasn't even possible!, the lovely dark case helps emphasise the phones design. The case is not slippery at all & I have yet to get any marks/ damage onto it" (★★★★★)</b> - Nuur Hassan (Samsung S8)</p>
  </div>

  <div id="cssSlider">
    <div id="sliderImages">
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide5.jpg" alt="" />
      <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="GalleryTXT">
    <p><b>"The MWS Bench case fits my new phone perfectly & is just gorgeous!, the wood has such a natural look to it but doesn't have that rough texture you get from natural wood, just lovely, very pleased with my purchase from MWS, will be coming back for more cases in the future. The website is also very easy to manage & just looks great, well done." (★★★★★)</b> - Shiva Sivanesan (iPhone 8)</p><br>
    <p><b>"This is my second purchase from MWS & it's just as good as my first purchase with the company. The case just looks amazing & fits the phone perfectly down to the smallest detail. The case feels very protective but doesn't feel like it could easily get damaged, very happy with purchase." (★★★★★)</b> - Shiva Sivanesan (iPhone 8)</p>
  </div>

  <div id="cssSlider">
    <div id="sliderImages">
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="http://f.cybrox.eu/codepen/slider/slide5.jpg" alt="" />
      <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Code is also available [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJgrZX)

Comment: If your image will adapt the size and width of the div. Then it might possible your image will get distorted.

Comment: How else would I stop the div from being to big for the page width then?, that's why I set the width to 90% so its always smaller than the width of the page.

Comment: Hard because your width is responsive, but your animation as step of 800px, I think that it cannot be done with the way your started....

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) into your project.

and try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;

  var height = $("#sliderImages").height();
  var width = $("#sliderImages").width(); // Here you can make it 90% by just computing a width

  $("#sliderImages img").css({ height: height, width: width });
});
```

Comment: Do I Just link JQuery with the CDN in the head tag & then put the Jquery Script you gave me in a script tag in the html?

Comment: Yes Exactly you have to do the same thing

Comment: Does it matter which version of the JQuery CDN I Use?

Comment: No. Include the latest file which I gave you.

Comment: Ok, It fills the div now but it still doesnt slide over to the next image, it slides over to the part of the image it didn't show.